# Saving Retrieved data to CSV in beautiful soup

Tags: java, python, csv, beautifulsoup

```
for row in page_soup.find("table",{"class":"table"}).tbody.findAll('tr'):

    first_column = row.findAll('td')[0].contents

    second_column = row.findAll('td')[1].contents

    third_column = row.findAll('td')[2].contents

    print(first_column, second_column, third_column)
```

Comment: I'm not positive what your question is.

Comment: i am receiving the data from a table in a website and it is showing in CMD promt, but i want to export it to cvs

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something as simple as:

```
for row in page_soup.find("table",{"class":"table"}).tbody.findAll('tr'):
    first_column = row.findAll('td')[0].contents
    second_column = row.findAll('td')[1].contents
    third_column = row.findAll('td')[2].contents

    print("\"" + first_column + "\",", "\"" + second_column + "\",", "\"" + third_column + "\"")
```

and redirect the output into a file.  However, that assumes a string for each column which may or may not be correct.  Remove the escaped quotes if the column type is numeric.